# Eclipse custom Java formatter for right braces to end of prior line?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to generate a custom Eclipse Java formatter that collapses the otherwise empty lines containing the block ending right braces onto the prior code line.

For example:

```
    if (a == b) {
        first();
        second();
    }
```

should be formatted as:

```
    if (a == b) {
        first();
        second(); }
```

and this:

```
    test: if (a == b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (c == d) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    // ...
                    break test;      
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

should format as:

```
    test: if (a == b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (c == d) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    // ...
                    break test; } } } }
```

and so on.

The Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Active Profile: "NewFormatter" -> Edit -> Brace Positions : list of options control the left brace, but the right brace seems to always be on a new line.  Has anyone solved this problem?

If this formatter can be accomplished in a relatively straight forward way I'll roll up my sleeves and dig into the formatter details.  But if it requires heavy code changes in Eclipse itself I'll have to skip it.  I'll appreciate any and all comments or suggestions.

Comment: In my opinion, if you want other people to easily read and understand your code, then you should follow Java coding conventions which Eclipse tries to enforce and which your desired format does not follow. Hence you are essentially asking Eclipse to format code in a way that Eclipse assumes will never be done. I believe that this cannot be done easily.

Comment: New formatters are supported, but they have to be an Eclipse plug-in. They require a lot of knowledge of the Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Table. A quick look at the default formatter shows it is at least 10,000 lines of code.

Comment: Abra, sorry I wasn't more clear.  I wouldn't suggest that anyone use my custom formatter, and of course if I publish my code, it would be viewed using the Eclipse standard format.

Comment: reg-449, thank you.